# git grep colors differ from grep custom colors

Tags: grep, configuration, colors, git

I've setup grep colors in my `~/.bashrc` :

```
export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;34:mc=01;34:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=32:se=36'
```

They work for

- `grep --color=auto`
- `grep --color=always`

Unfortunately, those custom colors are ignored by:

- `git grep --color=auto`
- `git grep --color=always`

How to make `git grep` to use above `$GREP_COLORS` colors ?

Comment: Git doesn't call the external `grep` utility, it has its own internal command which is called `git grep` and has similar but not identical options.

Answer (score 11):

Git grep is not using the `GREP_COLORS` environment variable. Instead you should add custom entries in you `~/.gitconfig`

For example:

```
[color "grep"]
    linenumber = yellow bold
    match = red
    filename = magenta
```

Comment: How do you do background?

Comment: @letitbee "The first color given is the foreground; the second is the background.", e.g `match 10 22`

- see `man 1 git-config` at "CONFIGURATION FILE" > "Values" > "color"

Answer (score 10):

You should explicitly configure colors in git's configuration file.

Interesting information are found in [git-config](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html) man page, in particular look for the configuration variable `color.grep.<slot>`

Answer (score 0):

But, you can override the values on execution with the -c option, for example like so:

`git -c color.grep.filename="13 23" -c color.grep.match="14" grep -e "README\."`

[link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt)